# Get values from Invoke-RestMethod PSobject

Tags: powershell, psobject

I am using [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) to pull employee data from our HRIS (human resource information system):

```
$employee = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $headers -Uri $URI -ContentType 'application/json'
```

It returns this PSobject and I am having trouble referencing the values:

```
employees                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
---------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
{@{account_id=12345; username=12345; is_locked=False; employee_id=12345; first_name=John; middle_initial=Roger; last_name=Doe; full_name=John Roger Doe}}
```

I am trying to pull the individual values to use as variables in the rest of the script.

---

Things I have tried:

`Write-Output ($employee | Select -ExpandProperty "first_name")`

`Write-Output $employee.Properties["first_name"].Value`

---

Complete script as requested

```
$APIkey = "supersecret"
$KronosAccount = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Kronos admin ID'
$KronosPassword = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Kronos password' -AsSecureString
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($KronosPassword)
$PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)

$loginheaders = @{}
$loginheaders.Add("Api-Key", $APIkey)
$loginheaders.Add("Accept", "application/json")


$json = @{
  credentials = @{
    username = $KronosAccount
    password = $PlainPassword
    company = '123456'
  }
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $loginheaders -Uri https://secure3.saashr.com/ta/rest/v1/login -ContentType 'application/json' -Body (ConvertTo-json $json) 
$tokenvalue = ($token | Select -ExpandProperty "token")

$NewEmployeeID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the employee ID to create an account for'

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Api-Key", $APIkey)
$headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authentication", "Bearer $tokenvalue")

$URI = "https://secure3.saashr.com/ta/rest/v1/employees/?company=123456&filter=username::$NewEmployeeID"
$employee = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers $headers -Uri $URI -ContentType 'application/json'

$employee.employees
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok you have some funky stuff going on there. The value you have presented as the return result from your Invoke-RestMethod is actually a deserialized PowerShell object, not JSON. It appears to be having its quotes removed at some point too.

If you do this:
`$x = @{account_id="12345"; username="12345"; is_locked="False"; employee_id="12345"; first_name="John"; middle_initial="Roger"; last_name="Doe"; full_name="John Roger Doe"}`

then you can do this:

`$x.full_name`

and get the value you want. I think you are going to want to reach out to whomever is hosting that API and have them fix this on there end.

To make sure this is problem is not being introduced client side, can you replace `Invoke-RestRequest` with `Invoke-WebRequest` (it should take all the same parameters). Then run `$employee.rawContent` and post the result. This will let us know for sure what is coming down the wire.

Comment: What is _"funky stuff"_ on that? Why should Invoke-RestMethod return a JSON String?

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` will not in the end return JSON, it will receive JSON and parse it into a PowerShell object. Given the output above, the parsed PowerShell object contains a deserialized PowerShell object, just without the double quotes you would expect. If I do a Invoke-RestMethod against an API that returns JSON I end up with a valid, parsed PowerShell object. In Brian's output, he has what appears to be a top level property that contains unparsed data.

Comment: omitted headers due to comment length. This is from `$employee.rawContent`
{"employees":[{"account_id":123456,"username":"123456","is_locked":false,"employee_id":"123456","first_name":"JOhn","middle_initial":"Mac","last_name":"Doe","full_name":"John Mac Doe"}]}`

Comment: This is strange because `Invoke-WebRequest` is giving you back valid JSON. I took the response string and ran it though `ConverFrom-JSON` to test like this:
`$x = '{"employees":[{"account_id":123456,"username":"123456","is_l‌​ocked":false,"employ‌​ee_id":"123456","fir‌​st_name":"JOhn","mid‌​dle_initial":"Mac","‌​last_name":"Doe","fu‌​ll_name":"John Mac Doe"}]}'
$y = $x | Convert-FromJSON`
Then I outputted the data:
`$y.employees`
and it works fine. This would suggest that the code that is involved with `Invoke-RestMethod` is messing with it's content. Can you do 2 things for me (see next)

Comment: 1. Run this just to make sure it doesn't work:
`$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $headers -Uri $URI`
`$x.employees`
2. Post your complete script so I can take a further look.
As a work-around, there is no reason why you cannot use the `Invoke-WebRequest` and `ConvertFrom-JSON` code above in place of `Invoke-RestMethod`

Comment: Thanks Ty, Trying the $x.employees resulted in no output and no errors, just returned to prompt. When doing the `invoke-webrequest` and `convertfrom-json` methods together, I get the exact same structure as returned by `invoke-restmethod`

Comment: Can you post your script in its entirety as well as post the results of `$PSVersionTable`

If this REST service is publicly accessible, could you also post that URL

Comment: Ty, I have updated the OP with the full script. Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

Comment: Ty, I messed up, when I tried doing `$x.employees` I was using `invoke-webrequest` not `invoke-resmethod` When I corrected that, I was able to get a correctly formatted object!

Comment: perfect, was just about to point out that you had webrequest without a conversion. Glad you are up and running.